# How to merge two plots in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to merge two plots, that is my dataframe:
 `df_inc.head()`

```
id  date    real_exe_time   mean    mean+30%    mean-30%
0   Jan           31        33.14   43.0         23.0
1   Jan           30        33.14   43.0         23.0
2   Jan           33        33.14   43.0         23.0
3   Jan           38        33.14   43.0         23.0
4   Jan           36       33.14    43.0         23.0
```

My first plot:
`df_inc.plot.scatter(x = 'date', y = 'real_exe_time')`

[image: scatter]

Then

My second plot:
`df_inc.plot(x='date', y=['mean','mean+30%','mean-30%'])`

[image: lines]

When I try to merge with:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax = df_inc.plot(x='date', y=['mean','mean+30%','mean-30%']);
df_inc.plot.scatter(x = 'date', y = 'real_exe_time', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

I got the following:

[image: fail]

How I can merge the right way?

Comment: Thanks @Ch3steR for the edit

Comment: Why would "Jan 3" be displayed as "Jan" in your first graph? What is this column? String? Datetime object? Is the posted code the code you used to generate these outputs?

Comment: @Mr.T Sorry for that, that column is just  "Jan", i gonna edit. And that collum is string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not repeat your mean values as an extra column. `df.plot()` for categorical data will be plotted against the index - hence you will see the original scatter plot (also plotted against the index) squeezed into the left corner.
You could create instead an additional aggregation dataframe that you can plot then into the same graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#test data generation
import numpy as np
n=30
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": np.random.choice(list("ABCDEF"), n), "real_exe_time": np.random.randint(1, 100, n)})
df = df.sort_values(by="date").reindex()

#aggregate data for plotting
df_agg = df.groupby("date")["real_exe_time"].agg(mean="mean").reset_index()
df_agg["mean+30%"] = df_agg["mean"] * 1.3
df_agg["mean-30%"] = df_agg["mean"] * 0.7

#plot both into the same subplot
ax = df.plot.scatter(x = 'date', y = 'real_exe_time')
df_agg.plot(x='date', y=['mean','mean+30%','mean-30%'], ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

You could also consider using [seaborn that has, for instance, pointplots for categorical data aggregation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just got to change de mean on external dataset because the mean is year_mean not just month by month mean

Comment: In this case, you have to feed the annual average for one year into `A`, `B`, `C` and that for the next year into `D`,`E`, and `F`. That probably could be optimized in the groupby aggregation but you did not provide your real data structure in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Guessing that you haven't transform the Date to a datetime object so the first thing you should do is this

```
#Transform the date to datetime object
df_inc['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_inc['date'],format='%b')
fig=plt.figure()
ax = df_inc.plot(x='date', y=['mean','mean+30%','mean-30%']);
df_inc.plot.scatter(x = 'date', y = 'real_exe_time', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Comment: All the data in date is String type, so I got the eror ```OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00```

Comment: Fixed, please check it

Comment: Diferent error:
```ValueError: time data '2021 Jan' does not match format '%Y %b %d' (match)```

Comment: Ohh as i can see now you don't have a day in the months. I fixed it check it out