# Plotting several plots in matplotlib using a list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple plot function:

```
def plot_data(dataset="boys", baby_name="David"):
    ax = dataset.T.sort_index().loc[:, baby_name].plot(legend = baby_name)

list_of_dict = [{"data": boys, "baby_name": "David",
                 "data": girls, "baby_name": "Susan",
                 "data": boys, "baby_name": "Colin",
                 "data": girls, "baby_name": "Frances"}]
for l in list_of_dict:
    ax = plot_data(l['data'], l['baby_name'])
```

I can layer up different plots by writing

```
ax = plot_data("boys", "David"])
ax = plot_data("boys", "Susan"])
```

But if I try to loop through the list and plot I only get one plot. Why is that?

The plot is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: check first answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66282157/how-to-merge-two-plots-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're redefining `ax` with each call to `plot_data` function. To retain the data across multiple calls to `plot_data` you need to define a top level `ax` and pass that as another parameter to `plot_data`. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29233885/3943564):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s+')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for key, grp in df.groupby(['color']):
    ax = grp.plot(ax=ax, kind='line', x='x', y='y', c=key, label=key)
```

Answer (score 0):

My way was to recognise that the data structure is a simply a list of dicts as alluded by both answers. I just changed the list and created a new dict for each. Simples.

```
list_of_dict = [{"data": boys, "baby_name": "David"},
                {"data": girls, "baby_name": "Susan"},
                {"data": boys, "baby_name": "Colin"},
                {"data": girls, "baby_name": "Frances"}]
for d in list_of_dict:
    ax = plot_data(d["data"], d["baby_name"])
```